# Weblogic Console Problem with pending folder xml's

Tags: xml, console, weblogic

As u know, weblogic server collects the changes which we did by the consele screen under "pending" folder. But my wl server is not creating that files correctly. For example, each line has an end with the characters `&#xd;` (which means\r), it adds xmlns to each element and finally it started to give the error "`Caused By: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Could not perform unpadding: invalid pad byte`" when I was trying to create a new datasource.

A simple example for the file structure is below:

```
    <domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" 
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/90/weblogic/security/samples http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd" 
xmlns:dom="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain"> &#xd;
```

as u can see there are 2 xsi attributes in it.

And also, whan I try to add a new datasource, it gives the exception "`Console encountered the following error com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Could not perform unpadding: invalid pad byte.`". But the xml file is correct(and it is not related with the password encryption)

What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All other examples I have seen earlier suggest a problem with the password encryption in the config.xml

I'll suggest you backup your config.xml and change `<credential-encrypted>` to plaintext instead of the encrypted value, and try again.

Also see this link http://anythingsimple.blogspot.com/2008/10/oracle-bea-weblogic-server-10-invalid.html

> You may need to re-encrypt your
>   password in the new domain by using
>   the BEA supplied
>   weblogic.security.Encrypt tool to
>   archive this goal.

Comment: I made a workaround to get rid of the error JSAFE_PaddingException. I changed the jdbc xml file which is under "pending" folder in bea and whan I activated the changes, the problem was solved. But the main case in here is, the exml files for update for original xml files which weblogic generated are not valid. It generates stupid and unnecessary tags, extra attributes etc. Do u have any thougts about that?

Comment: @Ali: it shouldnt be happening, are you transferring the XML files from unix to read on windows and hence the ASCII formatting getting messed up?

Comment: It is in my local environment(win 7). There is no file transferring. It generates it in runtime , I mean the xml files which are under pending folder. there is a stupid config which makes this mistake I think. The problem is still going on:(